# How to read a password encrypted key with java?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, private-key, jce, pkcs#8

I have private key stored in file in PKCS8 DER format and protected by password. What is the easiest way to read it?

Here is the code I use to load unencrypted one:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(privateKeyFilename);
byte[] privateKeydata = new byte[in.available()];
in.read(privateKeydata);
in.close();
KeyFactory privateKeyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec encodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeydata);
PrivateKey privateKey = privateKeyFactory.generatePrivate(encodedKeySpec);
```

It works fine for unencrypted keys with the same specification. By the way, I am using BouncyCastle.

I can view this private key using following openssl command

```
openssl pkcs8 -in ./privatekey.key -inform DER -passin pass:thisismypass
```

Please, Help!!!

**I,ve posted some solutions in my own answer to this topic. But I keep question unanswered in case anybody can help with making it work without extra library, just BouncyCastle.**

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution! Maybe its not so elegant, but... 
Here I will post two solutions:

1. Prefferable, but not working
2. Working one, but requires additional library

***First***:

I found a kind of solution [here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=758133&tstart=0), but it throws exception. Solution:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateCrtKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.*;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;

/*
 * This class demonstrates how to import an encrypted RSA private key as
 * generated by openssl. The input file is presumed to be in DER
 * format.
 */
public class ImportEncryptedPrivateKey
{
    public static byte[] readPK8FromFile(String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        File f = new File(fileName);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        byte[] theData = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        dis.readFully(theData);
        return theData;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
    {
        byte[] encryptedPKInfo = readPK8FromFile("rsapriv.pk8");
        EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo ePKInfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(
                encryptedPKInfo);
        char[] password = { 'p', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd' };
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ePKInfo.getAlgName());
        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password);
        // Now create the Key from the PBEKeySpec
        SecretKeyFactory skFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ePKInfo
                .getAlgName());
        Key pbeKey = skFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
        // Extract the iteration count and the salt
        AlgorithmParameters algParams = ePKInfo.getAlgParameters();
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, algParams);
        // Decrypt the encryped private key into a PKCS8EncodedKeySpec
        KeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = ePKInfo.getKeySpec(cipher);
        // Now retrieve the RSA Public and private keys by using an
        // RSA keyfactory.
        KeyFactory rsaKeyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        // First get the private key
        RSAPrivateCrtKey rsaPriv = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) rsaKeyFac.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);
        // Now derive the RSA public key from the private key
        RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(rsaPriv.getModulus(), rsaPriv.getPublicExponent());
        RSAPublicKey rsaPubKey = (RSAPublicKey) rsaKeyFac.generatePublic(rsaPubKeySpec);
    }

}
```

And my exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: No such algorithm: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13
```

***Second***:

And following this http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/pkcs8.html you can read about the second, working solution

Comment: +1 for not-yet-commons-ssl. You don't even need Bouncy Castle then.

Comment: For the second solution. Can you paste the code here? I can't open that link. What library did you use?

Comment: 404 on the second llink. Has anywone solved that 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13 issue ?

Comment: For anyone wandering: to solve first exception you need to play with algo name which you put into Cipher factory method and SecretKeyFactory factory method: instead of AlgName you should use different algorithm, which one depends on you key file. 'PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256' fits for me. I found this (and you could try this construction as is) `ePKInfo.getAlgParameters().toString()` as an algrorithm name.

Comment: To read the now dead link, refer to https://web.archive.org/web/20171113221445/http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/pkcs8.html

Answer (score 4):

This is my code and it work's :)

```
File f = new File(keyFile);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int)f.length()];
dis.readFully(keyBytes);
dis.close();
EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptPKInfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(keyBytes);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());
PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passwd.toCharArray());
SecretKeyFactory secFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());
Key pbeKey = secFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
AlgorithmParameters algParams = encryptPKInfo.getAlgParameters();
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, algParams);
KeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = encryptPKInfo.getKeySpec(cipher);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
return kf.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);
```

Comment: With just the JDK (no Bouncy Castle) I get "Cannot find any provider supporting 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13" (which is the id for PBEWithMD5AndDES).

Comment: any solutions ?

Comment: @Thilo: no, pbeWithMD5andDES is (rsadsi=1.2.840.113549).1.5.3 (one of 11 schemes from PKCS5v1, now retronymed PBES1) while rsadsi.1.5.<b>13</b> is PBES2 (the new generic scheme in PKCS5v2).