# How to convert pkcs8 key file to DER format in #C?

Tags: c#, openssl, pkcs#8

How to convert pkcs8 key file to DER format, to get Private and Public key in Xml format?

with openssl I can do it using:
openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in aaa010101aaa_FIEL.key -out aaa.txt

aaa010101aaa_FIEL.key is bynary file

I'm trying to do it with Bouncy Castle library but I have problems to create new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(...

there is a post to do that in java, but i need it in c#
[How to read a password encrypted key with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654949/how-to-read-a-password-encrypted-key-with-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the Answer!

```
            byte[] dataKey = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

        Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricKeyParameter asp =
            Org.BouncyCastle.Security.PrivateKeyFactory.DecryptKey(pass.ToCharArray(), dataKey);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
        System.IO.StringWriter stWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemWriter pmw = new PemWriter(stWrite);
        pmw.WriteObject(asp);
        stWrite.Close();
        return stWrite.ToString();
```

[How to Load pkcs8 binary file format key](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/C-How-to-Load-pkcs8-binary-file-format-key-td3042662.html#a3044312)

Comment: pass is string (the password), fileName is path to .key binary file in DER format

Answer (score 1):

BouncyCastle documentation is pretty sparse and I haven't done this exact thing, but you will want to use an Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader to read the file into a (probably) Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo, like this:

```
using (FileStream FS = File.Open("whatever.key"))
{
 using (TextReader TR = new StreamReader(FS))
    {
  PR = new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(TR);
  EPKI = (Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo)PR.ReadObject();
 }
}
```

and then EPKI.GetDerEncoded() would give you the DER formatted thing. No guarantees that this will work, but PemReader should at least put you on the right track.

Comment: In this code (I replaced PR for var PR, and EPKI for var EPKI),
PR returns a value, but EPKI returns null.
didn work :(