# How to decrypt a pkcs8 encrypted private key using bouncy castle?

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, private-key

i am trying to decrypt a pkcs8 encrypted private key using bouncy castle library. I parsed the file containing the private key using `PEMParser` provided by bouncy castle. I got `PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo` object. I am unable to get the `PrivateKeyInfo` object from this.
I am getting the following exception while trying to decrypt.

> org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException: unable to read encrypted data: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13 not available: No such provider: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13

here is the code which I used

```
PEMParser parser = new PEMParser(br);
PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo pair =       (PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo)parser.readObject();
JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder jce = new JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder();
                jce.setProvider("1.2.840.113549.1.5.13");
                InputDecryptorProvider decProv = jce.build(password.toCharArray());
                PrivateKeyInfo info = pair.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(decProv);
```

Comment: Did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654949/how-to-read-a-password-encrypted-key-with-java ?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried with jce.setProvider("BC"); instead of  jce.setProvider("1.2.840.113549.1.5.13");

**Edit to add solution provided by @PeterDettman :**

In addition to use jce.setProvider("BC"); also install the BC provider [bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation](http://bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation)

Comment: Yes tried that too. This is the exception i got 
org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException: unable to read encrypted data: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13 not available: No such provider: BC

Comment: @krk92 It should definitely be setProvider("BC"). Have you actually installed the BC provider? (http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation)

Comment: I didn't install BC provider. Now it worked after installing. Thank you.

Comment: This solved it for me, as well. The wiki has moved to the github repo, for reference: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/wiki/Provider-Installation

Answer (score 1):

`Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());`

thats whats missing